# How to remove jerky/unstable movement from the timeline animation while using NAO robot in real life

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

I made some timeline animations in choregraphe. They all work perfectly fine in the simulator, but once I use a real life robot the animations speed up or move in a jerk-like fashion in certain spots of the animation putting stress on the motors.

The motion is set to passive mode with 25 fps, I assume this is default, because I haven't touched this

I tried to allow more frames to pass between the moments the "speed up" occurs, but that doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

It's possible "background movements" are running at the same time as your animation. Before playing your animation, first disable autonomous life (the heart icon in Choregraphe), then make the robot stand up (sun icon). At this point the robot should be standing and completely motionless.

If your animation has issues in that state, then it could be something else, like the self-collision protection adjusting the motion on the fly, or the fall detection. In any way, that means you would have to fix your animation at this point.

Comment: As said by Sebastien (welcome here!), you should be sure no other movement are running. So be sure to deactivate autonomous life and some balancing. The self-collision protection could also have interaction with your movement (when hands are close or close to the body) so be sure to avoid collision or test once after disabling them. Good luck !